# Chrome Extension API: chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarm => console.log(alarm))
```

in my background script. It's not wrapped in any brackets. I have the following in a function that gets called:

```
console.log('test')
chrome.alarms.create('test', { delayInMinutes: 1 });
```

I can see `'test'` logged, but the `onAlarm` listener doesn't fire. What can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: It may be a bug like https://crbug.com/1271154. Try reinstalling the extension. Also make sure you have `alarms` in `permissions` in manifest.json.